# gdb - how to find current module for a stack frame

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, stack

After navigating to a stack frame with `f stack_frame_number` I might see its source code if debugging infos are present and up-to-date. Anyway, how to find out which module my **current stack frame** is into?

E.g.

```
(gdb) print current_module
Your stack frame is in libTest.so.1
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

Gdb [provides](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html) the symbol `$pc` as a synonym for the instruction pointer in the current frame.

You can use this with the [info symbol](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html) command to show the executable or shared library corresponding to that frame:

```
(gdb) info symbol $pc
pause + 20 in section .text of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
(gdb) info symbol $pc
main + 9 in section .text of /home/mp/m
```

Comment: I didn't find this to be very reliable unfortunately